# undefined local variable or method `is_expected' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x000000057b9aa8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems, rspec3, rspec-puppet

I wrote a test as follows:

```
  context "on #{os}" do
    it { is_expected.to compile.with_all_deps }
    it { is_expected.to create_class('acpid') }

    context 'base' do
      it { is_expected.to contain_package('acpid').with( :ensure => 'latest')}
      it { is_expected.to contain_service('acpid').that_requires('Package[acpid]') }
      it { is_expected.to contain_service('acpid').with({
        :ensure     => 'running',
        :enable     => true,
        :hasstatus  => true,
        :hasrestart => true,
        :start      => '/sbin/service haldaemon stop; /sbin/service acpid start; /sbin/service haldaemon start',
        })
      }
    end
  end
end
```

end
end

When I run rspec spec/classes/init_spec.rb; I get the following errors:

1) acpid supported operating systems on centos-6-x86_64 
     Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to compile.with_all_deps }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `is_expected' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x000000057b9aa8>
     # ./spec/classes/init_spec.rb:10:in`block (5 levels) in '

Comment: What version of RSpec? Also, would you please fix the formatting to make it more readable.

Comment: rspec has some repos.
If you install only rspec-rails so you can not use is_expect which is in rspec-core.
More info here: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/878